# Nginx rewrite how can remove some parts in the end of url?

Tags: nginx

I am complete new of this.

My current urls is like

https://domain/photographs/xx-xx.jpg/@@images/image/large

https://domain/photographs/yy-yyy-yyyy.jpg/@@images/image/large

and I want to cut all /@@images/image/large

So browser get it as https://domain/photographs/yy-yyy-yyyy.jpg

Is this possible to do with nginx rewrite? and can you tell me how?

Comment: @RichardSmith

Thanks for your prompt reply, is that possible to specify the whole end "/@@images/image/large" since there is also a "/@@images/image/preview" that no need to convert.

Comment: rewrite ^(.*\.jpg)/@@images/image/large $1 permanent; so this line will work?

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks a lot it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the end of a URI by capturing everything before the sequence of characters you are trying to remove.

For example:

```
rewrite ^(.*\.jpg)/@@images/image/large $1 permanent;
```

Comment: I have one more question, is the possible to rewrite that in the html so it don't act as a redirect?

Comment: If you mean edit the links in the html document as Nginx sends it to the browser, you may be able to use the [`sub_filter` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter).

Comment: Can you show me sample code of that... I am new user of this.

Comment: Maybe something like `sub_filter_once off; sub_filter '.jpg/@@images/image/large' '.jpg';`